# Movement during Combat Patrol

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, movement

I wonder about this section of the [Combat Patrol](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/combat-patrol-combat/) feat:

> You may move as part of these attacks, provided your total movement before your next turn does not exceed your speed.

It is not stated if the character may move before or after making the triggered attack and it doesn't seem obvious to me when looking at the attack of opportunity rules:

> An attack of opportunity “interrupts” the normal flow of actions in the round. If an attack of opportunity is provoked, immediately resolve the attack of opportunity, then continue with the next character’s turn

Let's say we have a monk character with a reach weapon and using the [Combat Patrol](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/combat-patrol-combat/) feat. Thanks to its unarmed strikes and its reach weapon, the monk threatens both its adjacent squares and the others in its weapon reach.

If an enemy adjacent to the monk uses a movement action, it will trigger an attack of opportunity. Does that mean that the monk can move before making the attack of opportunity to be able to do it with its reach weapon instead of its unarmed strike?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, yes.

The wording "You may move *as part* of these attacks" implies that you move before the triggered attack, and the movement is only used to get to the target to complete the attack.

If you are holding a reach weapon with a 5ft patrol bonus, it means that if an enemy is 15ft away, you can move 5ft to get into position to use the reach weapon and strike from 10ft. If you try and use your Unarmed strike, you will come up short 5ft, as you are only threatening from 10ft away with your Unarmed strikes.

The movement is clearly designed to be used to move in order to get into striking distance, and not to get a better position with the weapons you are currently using. I would definitely say that the movement is only to get into the square that is being threatened.

That being said, with your reach weapon, the enemy is technically within the threatened range of your patrol route. By that logic, yes, you could move to strike with your Reach Weapon, as that is a square within your patrol that is threatening the enemy. However, you'd be moving out of an adjacent square, and would thereby invoke an attack of opportunity from the enemy.

Comment: To be fair, there may be occasions when you will have a choice of squares to move from to be able to strike the provoking target. Not to mention, if you ONLY had a reach weapon, you don't threaten adjacent to you, and so might need to move to be able to attack an adjacent target. I would guess this is why there aren't any restrictions on the movement, as there are just too many situations to foresee.